# Solving Dinesman's multiple-dwelling example using clojure's core.logic/core.match

Tags: clojure, clojure-core.logic

After watching Sussman's lecture http://www.infoq.com/presentations/We-Really-Dont-Know-How-To-Compute, I am inspired to give core.logic and core.match a go. The only examples I know are those constraint problem solvers that I used to do as a kid. This one was an example used in the SICP course as well as being mentioned in the talk:

> Baker, Cooper, Fletcher, Miller, and Smith live on different floors of an apartment house that contains only five floors. Baker does not live on the top floor. Cooper does not live on the bottom floor. Fletcher does not live on either the top or the bottom floor. Miller lives on a higher floor than does Cooper. Smith does not live on a floor adjacent to Fletcher's. Fletcher does not live on a floor adjacent to Cooper's. Where does everyone live?

I found this on the rosettacode site:
http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Dinesman%27s_multiple-dwelling_problem#PicoLisp

But not too sure how that translates into clojure. I am hoping that someone can provide an example of solving this using core.logic or core.match

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution in core.logic. It's not exactly equivalent to the picolisp algorithm because we don't have the same primitives available, but it's the same general idea. Thanks for introducing me to the problem - it was fun to invent `permuteo` and `beforeo`, and I had my first excuse to use `conda`.  **Edit**: using `conda` there was horrible and wrong, and I'm back to `conde` now. Oh well, some day.

```
(ns dwelling.core
  (:refer-clojure :exclude [==])
  (:use clojure.core.logic))

(defn rembero [x l out]
  (fresh [head tail]
    (conso head tail l)
    (conde [(== x head) (== out tail)]
           [(fresh [new-out]
              (conso head new-out out)
              (rembero x tail new-out))])))

(defn permuteo [a b]
  (conde [(emptyo a) (emptyo b)]
         [(fresh [head tail b-tail]
            (conso head tail a)
            (rembero head b b-tail)
            (permuteo tail b-tail))]))

(defn beforeo [x y l]
  (fresh [head tail]
    (conso head tail l)
    (conde [(== x head) (fresh [more-tail]
                          (rembero y tail more-tail))]
           [(beforeo x y tail)])))

(defn not-adjacento [x y l]
  (fresh [head tail more]
    (conso head tail l)
    (resto tail more)
    (conde [(== x head) (membero y more)]
           [(== y head) (membero x more)]
           [(not-adjacento x y tail)])))

(run* [tenants]
  (fresh [a b c d e]
    (== [a b c d e] tenants)
    (permuteo tenants '[Cooper Baker Fletcher Miller Smith])
    (!= e 'Baker)
    (!= a 'Cooper)
    (!= a 'Fletcher)
    (!= e 'Fletcher)
    (beforeo 'Cooper 'Miller tenants)
    (not-adjacento 'Smith 'Fletcher tenants)
    (not-adjacento 'Fletcher 'Cooper tenants)))

;; ([Smith Cooper Baker Fletcher Miller])
```

Comment: Oh that is so cool =) Thank you so much! I'm going have a lot of fun in the next week playing around with how all of this works. (The entire concept of appending vowels after words hasn't clicked with me just yet).

Comment: Yeah, the vowels don't make any sense to me either. I just name all my logic-functions ending with `o` and hope for the best. `conda`, `conde`, and `condu` seem to be special cases in the language. From reading The Reasoned Schemer (which I highly recommend), I got the impression the `o` might stand for "once", but it still doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I found another puzzle here for core.logic https://github.com/swannodette/logic-tutorial... the 'zebra puzzle'

Comment: Another possible approach after @amalloy brought this to my attention https://gist.github.com/3043632. Also rembero and permuteo are now a part of core.logic.

Answer (score 2):

I just started journeying into LP myself, and my first effort is https://github.com/amalloy/doors, a solver for the automatically-generated logic puzzles at http://rooms.jmpup.com. Right now I have some relations defined that are generally-useful for all puzzles, but I haven't done any work on actually translating a particular puzzle into core.logic programmatically. You can see the one puzzle I've manually translated - [webpage presentation](http://rooms.jmpup.com/room.php?seed=345&level=0&rcnt=0&rank=0) and [core.logic encoding](https://github.com/amalloy/doors/blob/master/resources/sample.clj). Perhaps this will give you an idea of how to use core.logic, although I'm still new to it myself so there are bound to be imperfections.

### Edit

After looking over the picolisp solution, I don't think it translates directly to core.logic because, as far as I know, direct negation support does not exist yet.

Comment: I think I have to play that door game when I'm a little bit more sober =) How are you using the solver right now?